# Source not found chkstk.asm

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, structure

I am trying to practice structures, from a video my class provided me only difference is he is using an older version of visual studios, and when I try to step into the code I get the error source not found chkstk.asm I have no idea how to obtain this and googling brought me nothing. Here is the code I have so far if it serves any help. Honestly visual studio has brought me so many unknown new problems that I feel like going back to the simple text editor I used before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct{
char name[40];
short int number;
double wholesale;
double retail;
short int onHand;

}PRODUCT;

void fillInProducts(PRODUCT[], int* pSize);
void fillInProducts(PRODUCT inventory[], int *pSize){
    strcpy_s(inventory[*pSize].name, 40,"Handsaw");
    inventory[*pSize].number = 3456;
    inventory[*pSize].onHand = 12;
    inventory[*pSize].wholesale = 12.34;
    inventory[*pSize].retail = 23.99;
    (*pSize)++;
}

main(){


int effectiveSize=0;
    PRODUCT hammer = { "Hammer", 1234, 5.50, 8.99, 4 };
    PRODUCT inventory[500];
    fillInProducts(inventory, &effectiveSize);
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: That's funny—when I google "chkstk.asm" I find lots of useful info, including other Stack Overflow posts a lot like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's part of the compiler's runtime support. Whether you have it depends on which VS edition you use. The compiler will produce stack checking calls into `chkstk` at the start of functions which have large stack frames. Some more details here: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/debug/article.php/c19241/Adventures-with-chkstk.htm

Your `main` function has a very large stack frame due to the large array of `PRODUCT`. That's the source of the stack checking call. For your purposes, you can ignore it. You are not interested in debugging the runtime stack checking code. Just step over it and debug your code.

I must take issue with your `main` function. It should be `int main(void)`.